# Can I shrink images side by side when seen in small devices using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to keep the way my images display in desktop view. The problem is that when I reduce the screen size, then the images display one after another.

```
<div class="col-md-12">  
         <div class="col-md-6">
           @Html.Image(item.Path, "Image", "", "")              
        </div>         

        <div class="col-md-6">
           @Html.Image(item.Path, "Image", "", "")              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `xs` instead of `md` and better read the documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">  
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
           @Html.Image(item.Path, "Image", "", "")              
        </div>         

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
           @Html.Image(item.Path, "Image", "", "")              
        </div>
</div>
```